# css addressing not sequential elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I like to address the h2 following an div with "intro" in it, to give it `margin-top:1em` so the h2 (after the div with 'intro' in it) has more room above it

```
<div class="articleWide intro">
   <h2>This header must NOT be effected</h2>
   <p>...</p>
</div>

<div class="articleWide">
   <h2>I like to address ONLY this header because is must have an extra margin-top</h2>
   <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Have experimented with a selector like

```
.articleWide > h2
```

or

```
.articleWide ~ h2
```

but didn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 3):

You were using `.articleWide ~ h2` which will select `h2` elements that are general succeeding siblings of an element with class `articleWide`. You want to use the following selector instead:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/w6LNz/)

```
.articleWide.intro + .articleWide > h2 {
    margin-top:1em;
}
```

Which will select the `.articleWide` element that is a adjacent succeeding sibling of `.articleWide.intro` and select the direct child `h2` element.

Comment: this works like a charm but see that the next h2 in the same div is adresses too (of course!). I added :first-of-type (.articleWide.intro + .articleWide > h2:first-of-type {margin-top:1em} But... is this the smartest solution or can I achieve this in another way too?

Comment: @user1792635 Glad it worked; but yes, `:first-of-type` would be the best, you could alternatively [use `:first-child` (example)](http://jsfiddle.net/2WjW2/) but that assumes that the `h2` is always the first child. I'd stick with `:first-of-type`, that sounds solid and it *should* work in all situations: http://jsfiddle.net/V8cZt/

Answer (score 1):

Here a slightly different approach, just to give another perspective. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/7zESW/)

Styling probably should depend on the length of the article, total number of chapters and schemes on the rest of the site.

CSS

```
.articleWide {
    width: 90%;
    border: 0px solid green;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #E0DEE0;
    margin-bottom: 0px auto 5px auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.intro {
    background-color: #E6E4F5;
}
.articleWide h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.articleWide p {
    padding: 0 20px 10px 20px;
}
.articleWide:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```